# RemovalListener callback in guava caching api does not work correctly

Tags: java, caching, guava

I write following codes for test cache expiretion with using guava caching support.
in following code i create a cache, add 20 entry to it from key 11000 to 30000, after some sleep traverse exist keies in cache and search for two key (19000 and 29000)

```
import com.google.common.cache.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestGuavaCache {

  public static int evictCount = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Cache<Integer, Record> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .expireAfterWrite(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .concurrencyLevel(4)
            .maximumSize(100)
            .removalListener(new RemovalListener<Object, Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onRemoval(RemovalNotification<Object, Object> notification) {
                    evictCount++;
                    System.out.println(evictCount + "th removed key >> " + notification.getKey()
                            + " with cause " + notification.getCause());
                }
            })
            .recordStats()
            .build();

    int nextKey = 10000;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        nextKey = nextKey + 1000;

        myCache.put(nextKey, new Record(nextKey, i + " >> " + nextKey));

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    System.out.println("=============================");
    System.out.println("now go to sleep for 20 second");

    Thread.sleep(20000);

    System.out.println("myCache.size() = " + myCache.size());

    for (Integer key : myCache.asMap().keySet()) {
        System.out.println("next exist key in cache is" + key);
    }
    System.out.println("search for key " + 19000 + " : " + myCache.getIfPresent(19000));
    System.out.println("search for key " + 29000 + " : " + myCache.getIfPresent(29000));
}
}

class Record {

  int key;
  String value;

  Record(int key, String value) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
 }

}
```

After running above main method i see following result

```
1th removed key >> 11000 with cause EXPIRED
2th removed key >> 13000 with cause EXPIRED
3th removed key >> 12000 with cause EXPIRED
4th removed key >> 15000 with cause EXPIRED
5th removed key >> 14000 with cause EXPIRED
6th removed key >> 16000 with cause EXPIRED
7th removed key >> 18000 with cause EXPIRED
8th removed key >> 20000 with cause EXPIRED
=============================
now go to sleep for 20 second
myCache.size() = 12
search for key 19000 : null
search for key 29000 : null
```

I have 3 Question

1. why others key similar 17000,19000,25000 does not notified in
   RemovalListener
2. why iteration on cache keyset is empty while cache
   size is 12
3. why search for 19000 and 29000 is null while cache size
   is 12

Comment: thanks for share this question

Answer (score 3):

Directly from the Javadocs:

> If expireAfterWrite or expireAfterAccess is requested entries may be evicted on each cache modification, on occasional cache accesses, or on calls to Cache.cleanUp(). Expired entries may be counted by Cache.size(), but will never be visible to read or write operations.

Guava's caches do not clean up entries immediately once the expiration time passes; this is because it (deliberately) doesn't create an extra thread just for cache maintenance.  Cleanup is performed every so often on various query operations.  In particular, the above documentation explains that the `size()` method may temporarily count expired entries.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for anyone (like me) who spent hours trying to figure out the answer to the first question:

Creating a guava cache with a concurrency level of more than 1 internally creates a fixed number of hash table segments and assigns the entries to any of the created hash table segments. And RemovalListener gets notified only for those entries when cache access/writes happens on the hash table segments where the entries are present.